# can I use delayed_job in rails3 to run a ruby script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I have a rails "application" that interacts with an API that does most of the heavy work. This API are basically ruby scripts that are called to run at a given point in time. Each script runs between 5 to 10 mins depending on the process. I was thinking on using some type of queue app like delayed_jobs to handle the queue. The only concern I have is that I haven't found any documentation that says that delayed_jobs can execute these ruby scripts. Does anyone has experience doing something like this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I installed spawned gem and used it to spawn another process as a thread and wait for the script to finish.